# Bootsrap Carousel Data-slide Arrows are under slide image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel i am trying to add buttons/arrows to switch between slides I have assigned the position to be absolute, Its clickable and works but the arrows are under the image what could be the problem check here > [link](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/index.php)

Here is the code

```css
#myCarousel .carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Make the indicators larger for easier clicking with fingers/thumb on mobile */
  #myCarousel .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -20px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
  }
  #myCarousel .carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  #myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <a href="lest-sidebar.php"><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Order Cleaning" /></a>
</div>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:100%;height:auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:auto">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/test.png" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/test.png" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/test.png" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made mistake in your css

Check your `768px` css you were give `botton: -20px !important`, change

**This**

```
#myCarousel .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -20px !important;
    position:absolute !important;
}
```

**To**

```
#myCarousel .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0px !important;
    position:absolute !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

i see you are using `icomoon` css

So have to change this html

```
<a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
</a>
<a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

**TO**

```
<a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">
   <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>
</a>
<a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">
   <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
</a>
```

And give additional css

**CSS**

```
.left.carousel-control i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 45%;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.right.carousel-control i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 45%;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQdi2.png)

Comment: Still the arrows are not displayed, I don't really know if they are displayed at all at the moment

Comment: @WojtekT You need to add font-awesome css first in your `head` tag

Comment: @WojtekT i just update answer hope it will helps you

Comment: The arrows are displaying now but on the top of the screen See here > [link](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/index.php)

Comment: i just update my answer. you can use this css like this `.right.carousel-control i`

Comment: @WojtekT You get it?

Comment: I got it working but had to go back to my own html - `<a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>` It seems it doesnt work with `icon-arrow-right` Thank you Sir!